# Share shell script: file permissions question

Tags: macos, permission, script, file

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and recently I've made a small shell script which just shows a message on the screen. To run it, I had run

```
chmod +x test-script.sh
```

and then using `sh ./test-script.sh` ran it successfully. So if I want to send this to friends, do they have to run `chmod` again? If so, how can I prevent it?

Comment: You should not have had to do the `chmod` if in fact you ran it by `sh ./test-script.sh`.  The `sh` will read the file and run it regardless if the execute flag is set or not.  You only need the execute flag if you run it directly, like `./test-script.sh`

Comment: @Kent Can you say whether the file permissions will be preserved if the file is copied to a different machine?

Comment: Not really.  It depends on many things.  If it is sent as a single file via mail, then it will probably end up saved as the default for the recipient's mail program.  If you copy it via a USB memory stick, then provided the USB memory supports the permissions, it should be ok.  If you use scp over the network, the permissions will be preserved.  If you are sending it to other Macs, you could put your file(s) into a disk image (dmg), in which case all the permissions would be preserved (even if the dmg was mailed)

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct your friends to run it using `sh ./test-script.sh`. That would not require a `chmod +x` to be done.

If your friends also use OS X, another alternative is to package it as an app with `Automator` using the **Run Shell Script** action and share that with your friends. In this case the user can run it just like any other application on the system.

See [Creating Shell Script Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ShellScriptActions.html) in the Automator Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've found the appify script here at https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099 Strange thing is that I had to zip the app to preserve the file permissions.